# espresso testing used in fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, android-espresso

I've never used espresso before. Now i want to auto type some text in editText field fragment. I know only how to do it with Activity.

```
@LargeTest
public class EspressoTest {


    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<CheckInActivity> mActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(CheckInActivity.class);
    @Test
    public void testActivityShouldHaveText() throws InterruptedException {
        onView(withId(R.id.editText)).perform(clearText(), typeText("KI"));
    }
}
```

I have MainFragment hosted by MainActivity and editText is placed inside MainFragment layout.

Also is there a way in espresso to click on some text, so it could find the view by text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now i decided to use robotium because yet i don't know how to implement it using espresso
Robotium has such methods as waitForFragment and waitForActivity

Answer (score 2):

> Also is there a way in espresso to click on some text, so it could find the view by text?

To catch a view by its text you can do as in this example:

`onView(withString(R.string.editText)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));`

To catch a text or just a part of it, you can use (I think it's possible also in Robotium) Hamcrest matchers. Here you would find propably all matchers: [Hamcrest 1.3 Quick Reference](http://www.marcphilipp.de/downloads/posts/2013-01-02-hamcrest-quick-reference/Hamcrest-1.3.pdf)

To make it more clear, I would give you some examples:

```
onView(withId(R.id.textView)).check(matches(withText(startsWith("Hello"))));

onView(withId(R.id.action_bar_main)).check(matches(withText(String.valueOf(contains("Hello")))));

onView(withId(R.id.textView)).check(matches(withText(endsWith("Hello"))));
```

I think this would be also useful:

[How do I detect a view that I have created programmatically in espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34000017/how-do-i-detect-a-view-that-i-have-created-programmatically-in-espresso/34150980#34150980)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the view by text, you can use `onView(withText())`.

However, you may need to chain a couple of matchers to find exactly what you want. `allOf()` lets you do just this. You may also need to click into your text field before you can type.

```
onView(allOf(
    withId(R.id.editText),
    withText(R.string.edit_text)
)).perform(click(),
           clearText(),
           typeText("KI")
   );
```

I prefer to use `replaceText()` on most tests to save time.