# How do I detect a view that I have created programmatically in espresso

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I have this line of Espresso test code:

```
    onView(withId(R.id.rvWorkDaySchedule)).perform(swipeDown());
```

And `rvWorkDaySchedule` is shown in red in the editor of Android Studio because there is no such XML view id in the layouts - I create this RecyclerView programmatically.

So how do I detect views that have been inflated programmatically with Espresso?

Comment: Do you programatically inflate it with `R.id.rvWorkDaySchedule` id? I'm not quite sure about that one...

Comment: No, there is no R.id.rvWorkDaySchedule. I have a variable private RecyclerView rvWorkDaySchedule = new RecyclerView(this). And then I add it to the view hierarchy of the layout using flMainContent.addView(rvWorkDaySchedule)

Comment: `R.id.*` refer to the auto-generated values found in the R file... If you're adding the view programatically, find it's parent via ID and perform the swipe on it instead?

Comment: Can I get a parent's child then? Because there are one or two swipable elements present in the same parent

Comment: Yes, you just need to avoid the "by ID" lookup due to adding your view programatically (thus, it won't be in the R file, ergo it will be highlighted red in Android Studio).

`findViewById(...).getChildAt(0).` should work fine.

Comment: espresso does not provide neither findViewById() nor getChildAt() - onView(withParent(R.id.main_content)). when I click control + space here there are no useful methods

Comment: I'm sorry for misspeaking; I was referring to the casual `findViewById(...)` Java/Android way of finding (and obtaining) views/view references, and the `getChildAt(int id)` method which is available for all subclasses of `View`. 

Perhaps this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748303/selecting-child-view-at-index-using-espresso) could be of some assistance as they're exposing the `getChildAt(int)` call to Espresso.

Comment: Thanks Ill take a look at it and let you know what happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, Espresso allows you to use Hamcrest matchers in tests.

[Hamcrest 1.3 Quick Reference](http://www.marcphilipp.de/downloads/posts/2013-01-02-hamcrest-quick-reference/Hamcrest-1.3.pdf).

The most useful for catching the programmatically added views are `withChild`, `withParent`, `hasSibling`, and `hasDescendant`.

To make it more clear, I would give a simple example from my app:

```
onView(withId(R.id.action_bar_details))
        .check(matches(withChild(withChild(withText("Details")))));
```

Secondly, for `RecyclerView` tests in Espresso use `onData` methods instead `onView`.

[Espresso  2.1. Espresso Cheat Sheet Master](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/downloads/espresso-cheat-sheet-2.1.0.pdf)

Another example from my app - using `onData` method

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.listView)).atPosition(getRandomPosition()).
                onChildView(withId(R.id.item)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Finally, check these great Googles repository for get more examples

1. [GoogleSample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/)
2. [GoogleCodeLabs](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-testing/)